# TypeError: (intermediate value).bind is not a function, even though I´ve binded function

Tags: reactjs, onclick, this, bind

In the onClick function when trying to setState({}) within the axios-function I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).bind is not a function
```

This derives as said from the setState({}) function. The weird thing is that I have bounded the function in the right way (I think) but it still gives the error message :/

**Does anyone know what might be wrong?**

---

**Render function**

```
  render() {
    const { params, subcatItems } = this.props
    const { subcategory, category } = params
    const subcat = params ? subcategory : null

    return (
      <div id="subCategoryList">
        <ul>
          {this.renderDivs(subcatItems, subcat, category)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**renderDivs()**

```
  renderDivs(subcatItems, subcat, category) {
    let nestedElement = []

    if (this.state.seriesList.length>0) {
      nestedElement = this.renderNestedList()
    }

    let categoryList = []
    for (var item in subcatItems) {
      if (item != '_id') {
        if (subcatItems[item].parent==category) {
          console.log('RenderDivs', this.state)
          categoryList.push(<li
                              onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, item, subcatItems[item].parent)}
                              key={item}
                              className={subcat == replaceSpecialCharactersURLs(item) ? "active" : null}>
                              {subcatItems[item].name}
                              {nestedElement}
                            </li>)
        }
      }
    }
    return categoryList
  }
```

**onClick()**

```
  onClick(subcategory, category) {
    browserHistory.push('/webshop/'+category+'/'+subcategory)

    axios.get('/products/subcategory/'+subcategory)
    .then(function (response) {
      let seriesList = []
      for (var index in response.data) {
        let seriesName = response.data[index].series
        if (seriesName) {
          seriesList.push(seriesName)
        }
      }

      this.setState({ seriesList: 'hej' }.bind(this))
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Comment: this.setState({ seriesList: 'hej' }.bind(this)) I think you are trying to bind the object there.

Answer (score 0):

Because `bind(this)` with `setState` is not required:

```
this.setState({ seriesList: 'hej' }.bind(this))
```

Simply write it like this:

```
this.setState({ seriesList: 'hej' })
```

Use this part:

```
onClick(subcategory, category) {
    browserHistory.push('/webshop/'+category+'/'+subcategory);

    axios.get('/products/subcategory/'+subcategory)
    .then(function(response) {
        let seriesList = []
        for (var index in response.data) {
            let seriesName = response.data[index].series
            if (seriesName) {
                seriesList.push(seriesName)
            }
        }

        this.setState({ seriesList: 'hej' })
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

or use arrow functions:

```
onClick(subcategory, category) {
    browserHistory.push('/webshop/'+category+'/'+subcategory)

    axios.get('/products/subcategory/'+subcategory)
    .then(response => {
        let seriesList = []
        for (var index in response.data) {
            let seriesName = response.data[index].series
            if (seriesName) {
                seriesList.push(seriesName)
            }
        }

        this.setState({ seriesList: 'hej' });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

**Note**: Instead of using callback methods and `.bind(this)`, use arrow functions:

```
axios.get('/products/subcategory/'+subcategory)
.then(response => {
})
.catch(error => {
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it does still not work with the arrowfunction s and it did not work with removing .bind(this)) after setState!

Comment: Worked for me. Gratitude @AlfredOdling!